# Contract state won't change during Truffle tests

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, testing, truffle-test

I am trying to test my contracts using the Truffle suite, along with Ganache.

Up until now, I have been testing contract functions which are restricted to `view` only.  Now, when I attempt to make changes to the contract state, I'm finding that the state is not *actually* being changed between function calls.

Consider the following simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "../OrderBook.sol";

contract IdManager {
    uint256 newId;

    function addId() public returns (uint256) {
        newId++;
        return newId;
    }
}
```

All I wish to do is increment `newId` and return its new value.

The code I have written to test this is:

```
const { getWeb3, getContractInstance, parseSignature } = require("./test_helper");
const web3 = getWeb3();
const getInstance = getContractInstance(web3);

contract('IdManager', (accounts) => {
    let IdManager = getInstance('IdManager');

    it('test addId()', async () => {
        console.log(await IdManager.methods.addId().call());
        console.log(await IdManager.methods.addId().call());
        console.log(await IdManager.methods.addId().call());
    });
});
```

The `getInstance()` call is making use of `Web3 v1.0`, based off [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@adrianmcli/migrating-your-truffle-project-to-web3-v1-0-ed3a56f11a4).

With the above test, I would expect the output to be:

```
1
2
3
```

But, I actually get:

```
1
1
1
```

Has anyone come across this issue before?

---

**Edit0:**

`console.log(await IdManager.methods.newId().call());` *should* have been `console.log(await IdManager.methods.addId().call());`—`newId()` is now `addId()`.

---

**Edit1:**

Taking goodvibration's advice, I have modified the example contract to be as follows:

```
contract IdManager {
    uint256 public newId;

    function addId() public {
        newId++;
    }

    function getId() public view returns (uint256) {
        return newId;
    }
}
```

The test code has been altered to the following:

```
it('test addId()', async () => {
    await IdManager.methods.addId().call();
    console.log(await IdManager.methods.getId().call());

    await IdManager.methods.addId().call();
    console.log(await IdManager.methods.getId().call());

    await IdManager.methods.addId().call();
    console.log(await IdManager.methods.getId().call());
});
```

Unfortunately, my output is still showing that the state is not being preserved:

```
0
0
0
```

Comment: You're not calling `addId` anywhere in your test!!!!!

Comment: I have updated my question, `newId()` should have been `addId()`.  Apologies.

Comment: What is `OrderBook`??? Is that possibly the old contract which you were trying to run this test with?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not having a very good day.  I'm pulling from the wrong set of tests there!  I have updated my question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution to this was right under my nose.  Obviously, I just had to *read* the documentation given to me.

[methods.myMethod.call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-call)

> Note calling **can not alter the smart contract state**.

[methods.myMethod.send](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#contract-send)

> Note this **can alter the smart contract state**.

So, the alteration to the last passage of test code in my question is as follows:

```
it('test addId()', async () => {
    await IdManager.methods.addId().send({from: accounts[0]});
    console.log(await IdManager.methods.getId().call());

    await IdManager.methods.addId().send({from: accounts[0]});
    console.log(await IdManager.methods.getId().call());

    await IdManager.methods.addId().send({from: accounts[0]});
    console.log(await IdManager.methods.getId().call());
});
```

Which results in my desired output:

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Function `addId` is a non-constant function (i.e., not declared as `pure` or `view`).

As such, its return-value can be used only in the on-chain, i.e., by other functions (in the same contract or in other contracts) which call it.

When you call such function from the off-chain, then a transaction is executed in the on-chain, and what you get in return is a receipt of that transaction.

If you want the actual return-value, then you need to `emit` it in an `event`, which you will later be able to extract from the receipt.

For example:

```
event Event(uint256 val);
function addId() public returns (uint256) {
    newId++;
    emit Event(newId);
    return newId;
}
```

Alternatively, since in your specific case you are returning the value of a global (state) variable, you can declare it `public`, and then simply read it from the contract using its (implicit) getter function:

```
console.log(await IdManager.methods.newId().call());
```

Comment: I should have remembered that executing such functions only returns the Tx receipt, from when I was solely using `Web3` and `remix`!  But, I have altered my test code to retrieve the member `Id` via a separate function call.  I am still not seeing a change in state between calls.

Answer (score 0):

As of December 2021, Truffle has changed the way contract should be called. This question is extremely important for someone as inattentive as I am so here's a sample test for the contract from **Edit1**

```
const idmanager= artifacts.require("IdManager"); 

contract('IdManager', async accounts => {

    it('test addId()', async () => {
        const instance = idmanager.deployed(); 

        await instance.addId({from: account[0]}); 
        const actual = await instance.getId.call({from: account[0]});

        assert.equal(actual, 1); 
    });
});
```